# Error creating new twitter application

Tags: twitter

I try to create new twitter application on https://apps.twitter.com/app/new link and
I got error message:
Error
You must confirm your email address prior to creating an application. Please read https://support.twitter.com/articles/97942-confirming-your-email-address for more information

I followed  by url above and made steps for creating account
http://s16.radikal.ru/i190/1408/75/a1c2cbdd451e.png
I use gmail account, but I still did not receive any  confirmatiom email. How knows what is wrong ?
About 24 hours has gone...
Anybody knows if service works ?

Comment: Seems so: http://status.twitter.com/.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand : seems that was unsuccesful time ? I tried again and several times get error: "Error
The form has become outdated. Copy any unsaved work in the form below and then reload this page."

Comment: I guess you should just sign up regularly and then go to your link. Then you will have your account shown in the upper right corner. That should help.